# How do I use my MIDI drums in Guitar Hero World Tour for PC?

Tags: pc, guitar-hero

I've got my electronic Fame MIDI drum connected to my PC. It supports MIDI. Now I want to use this in Guitar Hero World Tour.

GHWT does not seem to recognise my drum controller. I downloaded the drum tuning kit, and this recognises the drums and is able to send a test signal, but no luck with the actual tuning because none of the pads light up when drumming.

How do I use my MIDI drums in Guitar Hero World Tour for PC?

Answer (score 2):

Guitar Hero World Tour only supports game controllers, not midi controllers. You can circumvent this by using [GlovePIE](http://glovepie.org/).